# Using REST VSTS API - Is it possible to remove/delete a test point?

Tags: c#, rest, api, azure-devops

I am creating test suites and then assigning test cases to the test suites using the VSTS REST API.

After I create the test suite, I update the test suite by adding 4 default configurations using the method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365286/using-rest-vsts-api-update-existing-test-suite-configurations). However, not all of my test cases need to be tested with all 4 configurations. Meaning that some only need to be tested with 1 configuration while others might need 3 configurations.

My problem is that by adding the test case to the test suite, all 4 configurations are set to the test case. I understand why this is happening, but I'd like to remove the configurations from the test cases that do not need them. My understanding is that these are called test points. I can get the test points and I can update the test points but I cannot delete the test points.

Is there a way to delete a single test point using the VSTS REST API? If not, is there a work around or other possible means to do this.

Note: I am using the [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/) 15.131.0-preview build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, there is no way to update test case’s configuration by REST API.

And there has an user voice [VSTS REST API assign test configurations to test case](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32668729-vsts-rest-api-assign-test-configurations-to-test-c) which suggests similar feature, you can vote and follow up.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have voted at the link you have provided. In the meantime I found a work-around, although a painful one. I use the older API for TFS and I update the Default Configurations on the test suite before adding each test case to the test suite. It's painful because the code is jumping through hoops to get the correct configurations assigned to the test cases for the test suite. But it works in the meantime until there is a better solution.